# Trying to use HttpClient.GetStreamAsync straight to the adls FileClient.UploadAsync

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, dotnet-httpclient, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have an Azure Function that will call an external API via HttpClient. The external API returns a JSON response. I want to save the response directly to an ADLS File.

My simplistic code is:

```
public async Task UploadFileBulk(Stream contentToUpload)
{
   await this._theClient.FileClient.UploadAsync(contentToUpload);            
}
```

The this._theClient is a simple wrapper class around the various Azure Data Lake classes such as DataLakeServiceClient, DataLakeFileSystemClient, DataLakeDirectoryClient, DataLakeFileClient.

I'm happy this wrapper calls works as I expect, I spin one up, set the service, filesystem, directory and then a filename to create. I've used this wrapper class to create directories etc. so it works as I expect.

I am calling the above method as follows:

```
await dlw.UploadFileBulk(await this._httpClient.GetStreamAsync("<endpoint>"));
```

I see the file getting created in the Lake directory with the name I want, however if I then download the file using Sorage Explorer and then try to open it in say VS Code it's not in a recognisable format (I can "force" code to open it but it looks like binary format to me).

If I sniff the traffic with fiddler I can see the content from the external API is JSON, content-type is application/json and the body shows in fiddler as JSON.

If I look at the calls to the ADLS endpoint I can see a PUT call followed by two PATCH calls.

The first PATCH call looks like it is the one sending the content, it has a content-header of application/octet-stream and the request body is the "binary looking content".

I am using HttpClient.GetStreamAsync as I don't want my Function to have to load the entire API payload into memory (some of the external API endpoints return very large files over 100mb). I am thinking I can "stream the response from the external API straight into ADLS".

Is there a way to change how the ADLS FileClient.UploadAsync(Stream stream) method works so I can tell it to upload the file as a JSON file with a content type of application/json?

EDIT:
So turns out the External API was sendng back zipped content and so once I added the following extra AutomaticDecompression code to my functions startup I got the files uploaded to ADLS as expected.

```
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("default", client =>
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        });
    }
```

@Gaurav Mantri has given me some pointers on if the pattern of "streaming from an output to an input" is actually correct, I will research this further.

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65615193/how-to-set-contentmd5-in-datalakefileclient.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post with the answer on why I was getting binary data, but your comment has given me a good start on how to code the pattern "stream from a result to an input".

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
var uploadOptions = new DataLakeFileUploadOptions();
uploadOptions.HttpHeaders = new PathHttpHeaders();
uploadOptions.HttpHeaders.ContentType ="application/json";
await fileClient.UploadAsync(stream, uploadOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks @jim, I've updated the post with the answer on why I was getting binary data